# How to smoothen transition of width and height?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I have created this animation but it is not smooth. When you hover over the blue circle, a multicolored circle opens up but the opening is shaky, not 100% smooth. Can the animation be smoothened and how?

```css
#container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  position: relative;
}
#circle {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: width 0.2s, height 0.2s;
}
#circle a {
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  width: 250px;
  height: 220px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
#circle a:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#trap1 {
  background-color: green;
  transform: rotate(0deg) skewX(30deg);
}
#trap2 {
  background-color: yellow;
  transform: rotate(60deg) skewX(30deg);
}
#trap3 {
  background-color: red;
  transform: rotate(120deg) skewX(30deg);
}
#trap4 {
  background-color: blue;
  transform: rotate(180deg) skewX(30deg);
}
#trap5 {
  background-color: orange;
  transform: rotate(240deg) skewX(30deg);
}
#trap6 {
  background-color: purple;
  transform: rotate(300deg) skewX(30deg);
}
#hide {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: cyan;
}
#circle:hover {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="circle">
    <div id="hide"></div>
    <a id="trap1"></a>
    <a id="trap2"></a>
    <a id="trap3"></a>
    <a id="trap4"></a>
    <a id="trap5"></a>
    <a id="trap6"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it doesn't seems shaky on my browser, maybe too fast .. did you give a try such as : transition: linear 0.35s ?

Comment: It's smooth for me. Wonder if it's your machine that is under-powered or overloaded?

Comment: Agree with the commenters above...  looks nice and smooth here.  Run your program on better hardware.

Comment: It shakes a little ... I'm on windows google chrome

Comment: On Linux google chrome, and it jitters a bit for me too.

Comment: Is this problem only occurring on chrome, as i am also using Chrome on Windows 8.1 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Reason:** (no links/source to back-up, it is just an educated guess)

I've run into similar a case in the past and what I've managed to find out is that the shake happens due to (I believe) a sub-pixel rendering issue.

When  `height` and `width` are transitioned, the updates to the element seem to happen pixel by pixel. For example, in the below snippet there are two `div` elements whose `height` and `width` are being transitioned (first one increases by `3px` over `5s` while second increases by `5px`). The key thing to note here is that for the first `div` there are three visible steps while there are five steps for the second one (meaning they increase pixel by pixel).

```css
div{
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 10px;
  transition: all 5s linear;
}
div:nth-child(1):hover{
  height: 103px;
  width: 103px;
}
div:nth-child(2):hover{
  height: 105px;
  width: 105px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Now you would ask me how does this have any connection with the shake. The connection is that the `height` and `width` increase pixel by pixel but the `translate(-50%, -50%)` means that the no. of px by which to translate the element is sometimes in fractions and it seems like some corrections happen during the actual transition to overcome these fractional values.

---

**Solution:** (or a work-around)

Instead of using `translate(-50%, -50%)` trick for horizontal + vertical centering, if we directly position the element by providing the `top` and `left` in pixels, you'd see that there is no shake. Based on my understanding, this is because browsers transition all 4 properties (`height`, `width`, `top` and `left`) pixel by pixel and hence there are no fractional values that cause the correction.

(*Tested on the latest Chrome + Windows 10.*)

```css
#container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  position: relative;
}
#circle {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 275px;
  left: 275px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
#circle a {
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  width: 250px;
  height: 220px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
#circle a:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#trap1 {
  background-color: green;
  transform: rotate(0deg) skewX(30deg);
}
#trap2 {
  background-color: yellow;
  transform: rotate(60deg) skewX(30deg);
}
#trap3 {
  background-color: red;
  transform: rotate(120deg) skewX(30deg);
}
#trap4 {
  background-color: blue;
  transform: rotate(180deg) skewX(30deg);
}
#trap5 {
  background-color: orange;
  transform: rotate(240deg) skewX(30deg);
}
#trap6 {
  background-color: purple;
  transform: rotate(300deg) skewX(30deg);
}
#hide {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: cyan;
}
#circle:hover {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="circle">
    <div id="hide"></div>
    <a id="trap1"></a>
    <a id="trap2"></a>
    <a id="trap3"></a>
    <a id="trap4"></a>
    <a id="trap5"></a>
    <a id="trap6"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So you are saying, the width and height start increasing/decreasing wrt top left corner of a div, and since I want my shape to be centered, I should move the top left corner back to top: 50px and left: 50px, and since browsers transitions all 4 properties pixel by pixel, hence my transition will be smooth ?

Comment: It's kind of difficult to explain @DhruvChadha. What looks like happening is this - first the div is positioned at top 50% (which is 300px) and then translated by -50% (which is half the element's height = -25px). When transition starts, at the first step the position is still 300px but the translate is now by -25.5px (because the height is 51px) and so on... As per my understanding, it is there fractional values that cause a problem. When you relieve the browser from having to calculate the 50% values, it seems to become smoother.

Comment: In my answer, I had done away with this `translate(-50%, -50%)` totally. Originally the container is 600px and circle is 50px, so `top: 50%` + `translate(-50%, -50%)` would mean the element is actually at `top: 275px` (600-50/2) and I have set this default to the `#circle`. After full transition, the element would be at (600-500/2) and so within the hover selector, I've set it as `top: 50px`. I have basically used a direct method to center the element than use `translate`.

Comment: Yes, i understand that, one cannot move by fractional pixels as pixels are the smallest block of a single color on a screen... but in the solution you provided, is my understanding right of what is happening ? (as written in first comment)

Comment: Yes, that's correct @DhruvChadha. Since the element's dimensions have changed, we should move it even more to the top-left, that is, from (275,275) to (50,50) for it to look centered even after the transition.

Comment: As always, your way of explaining CSS enthrals me, thank you sir.